# Function Composition issues

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

i want to use the function composition in both ways with brackets and without.
i try this :

```
let d = (+5) 
 Prelude> d ( d ( d 2))
 17
```

but if try this :

```
Prelude> d . d . d 2

<interactive>:12:1: error:
    * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> c)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
```

why is this happening ? it should be semantic equivalent or not ?

```
 d . a x <=> d (a x) ?
```

Comment: But function application binds tighter than operators.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, function application is of higher precedence than `.` so it gets parsed as `d . d . (d 2)`. You'll need to put your function composition in parens like this: `(d . d . d) 2`.

Comment: Or `d . d . d $ 2`.